# How to remove an item arrays as JSON objects in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an **JSON** array object list :

```
[
  "image1.png",
  "image2.jpg",
  "image3.jpg",
  "image4.jpg",
  "image5.jpg",
  "image6.jpg"
]
```

When i **unset** one of item in top list array like bottom ***php*** code :

```
unset($json[2]);
```

*$json[2]* **is** *"image3.jpg"*

But after remove item ,list will change to bottom list :

```
{
  "0": "image1.png",
  "1": "image2.jpg",
  "2": "image4.jpg",
  "4": "image5.jpg",
  "5": "image6.jpg"
}
```

What's right way to be like bottom list ? :

```
[
  "image1.png",
  "image2.jpg",
  "image4.jpg",
  "image5.jpg",
  "image6.jpg"
]
```

Please Help me ..
Thank You ..

Comment: May create an new index with `$json = array_values($json);` after `unset`.

Comment: @devlin carnate jep, an json array :)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thank You Dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As order of keys in your array has changed after removing a certian key, `json_encode` tries to save this new order. So, you need to reindex your array keys.

For this use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values), which

> indexes the array numerically

```
$json = [/* your array here */];
unset($json[2]);
echo json_encode(array_values($json));
```